# ¿Como meter StreamBuilder en Scaffold con un ListView?

Tags: flutter

### Mi `_listStreamPlays` retorna un `StreamBuilder` Funcionando

```
Widget _listStreamPlays(BuildContext context){
    playlistBloc.obtenerPlaylist();
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: StreamBuilder<List<Playlist>>(

        stream: playlistBloc.plalistStream,
        builder: ( context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Playlist>> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          final plays = snapshot.data;
          if (plays.length == 0) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('No hay registros'),
            );
          }
          listPlay = plays;
          return ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: plays.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>ListTile(
              // leading: Icon(Icons.cloud_queue, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
              title: Text(plays[index].playlistTitulo),
              subtitle: Text(plays[index].idPlaylist.toString()),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color:Colors.green,),
              onTap: () => navigateToDetail(plays[index], context),
            ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

El cual si lo intento meter en un `Scaffold` que tiene un `Column` ya no funciona

### Lo que necesito

Necesito un `Scaffold` por que dependiendo de como se llegue a la pantalla puede mostrar un `AppBar` o no mostrarlo, por lo tanto intente hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buttonNewPlay(context),
          _listStreamPlays(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
```

pero me manda un error que no deja mostrar el los datos del `ListView` por lo tanto tenia que poner el parametro `shrinkWrap: true,` para que se muestren, pero haciendo el `ListView` ya no hace scroll y manda error por el tamaño de pantalla
Utilizo un `Column` por antes del `ListView` quiero que baya un `RaisedButton`

manda un error bastante extenso pero pongo solo el inicio del error.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3179): The following assertion was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 3179): A RenderFlex overflowed by 184 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 3179):
I/flutter ( 3179): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 3179): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 3179): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 3179): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 3179): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 3179): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 3179): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter ( 3179): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter ( 3179): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 3179): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#81f60 relayoutBoundary=up4 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter ( 3179):   needs compositing
I/flutter ( 3179):   creator: Column ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
I/flutter ( 3179):     AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#7ff39 ink
I/flutter ( 3179):     renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← PhysicalModel ←
I/flutter ( 3179):     AnimatedPhysicalModel ← Material ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 3179):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
I/flutter ( 3179):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=504.0)
I/flutter ( 3179):   size: Size(360.0, 504.0)
I/flutter ( 3179):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 3179):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 3179):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 3179):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 3179):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 3179): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te dice que tienes un error al momento de hacer el `layout` de los widgets, parece que no tiene un `height` definido , está infinito, así que puedes usar un `SizedBox` para especificar el tamaño, así:

```
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
child: StreamBuilder<List<Playlist>>(
  stream: playlistBloc.plalistStream,
  builder: ( context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Playlist>> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    final plays = snapshot.data;
    if (plays.length == 0) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No hay registros'),
      );
    }
    listPlay = plays;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buttonNewPlay(context),
          Container(

            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: plays.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>ListTile(
                title: Text(plays[index].playlistTitulo),
                subtitle: Text(plays[index].idPlaylist.toString()),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color:Colors.green,),
                onTap: () => navigateToDetail(plays[index], context),
              )),
          ),
        ],
      ), ) ,
    );
  },
), ) ;
```

**Updated**

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        _buttonNewPlay(context),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: plays.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(plays[index].playlistTitulo),
                    subtitle: Text(plays[index].idPlaylist.toString()),
                    trailing: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    onTap: () => navigateToDetail(plays[index], context),
                  )),
        ),
      ]),
    );
```

Comment: utilice el `SizedBox` igual manda error pero si agrego `shrinkWrap: true,` si muestra los datos, pero me sigue mandando error por el tamaño y no se puede hacer scroll

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada, le agregué un `SingleChildScrollView` al `Column`, `shrinkWrap` true al listview , y se le quita el scroll para que lo maneje el parent

Comment: ok, Puse lo que dices y ya funciona, pero me hace Scroll a todo, edite mi pregunta para mostrar mas o menos lo que intente  para que mi `RaisedButton` siempre se mantenga en la misma posición. y lo único que se desplace sea el listView

Comment: ahí actualicé el código, más fácil aún

Comment: Listo unicamente para que si haga Scroll quite `shrinkWrap: true,`  y  `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` , por que de lo contrario el `ListView` no hace scroll